# Looping through project bookmarks using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, bookmarks

How can I access a project's bookmarks using PyQGIS?

Answer (score 1):

`QgsProject.instance().bookmarkManager().bookmarks()`

Will return a list you can loop through normally.